# Have the role ACTUATOR can not access sensitive HTTP endpoints

Tags: java

I'm using spring security,The following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "actuator", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ACTUATOR')")
public boolean getActuator(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.isUserInRole("ACTUATOR");
}
```

use postman return 200 OK and 'true'

but When i access any sensitive port return 401 and JSON

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-09-14 22:29:29",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/mappings"
}
```

I tried configuring the management.security.roles,
But neither ACTUATOR nor ROLE_ACTUATOR does not work

```
management: 
  security:
    enabled: true
    roles: ACTUATOR
```

My security configuration is as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
    }
}
```

My OAuth2 configuration is as follows

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    configurer.userDetailsService(sysUserService);
}

//@formatter:off
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient(client)
    .secret(secret)
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
    .scopes("read", "write")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
    .resourceIds("resource");
}
//@formatter:off
```

I configured

```
  management: 
    security:
      enabled: false
```

access configprops

```
"managementServerProperties": {
    "prefix": "management",
    "properties": {
        "security": {
            "enabled": false,
            "roles": [
                "ACTUATOR"
            ],
            "sessions": "STATELESS"
        },
        "address": null,
        "port": null,
        "addApplicationContextHeader": true,
        "contextPath": "",
        "ssl": null
    }
}
```

me use spring-boot1.5.4

Answer (score 0):

i added the following configuration

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

Reference link
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/993